# Java JOptionPane custom draw on background

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane, jdialog

I made a Java Desktop Application with a Swing GUI. In the menu bar there is a "About" entry. When clicking this "About" menu item, a JDialog is displayed using *JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...)* with an icon, a text about my program and a "OK"-Button to close the dialog.

I want to draw an effect of one or more balls (circles) that move around in the background of the dialog and changeing their colors.

**UPDATED code with the solution of @Titus:**

Custom JOptionPane class:

```
class MyEffectPane extends JOptionPane {

    public MyEffectPane(String message, int type){
        super(message, type);

        makeOpa(this);
    }

    // needed to make the drawings visible
    void makeOpa(JComponent comp){
        for(Component c : comp.getComponents()){
            if(c instanceof JPanel){
                JPanel p = (JPanel)c;
                p.setOpaque(false);
                makeOpa(p);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g.fillOval(width/2-50, height/2-50, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Call / show dialog:

```
MyEffectPane pane = new MyEffectPane("message....", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(this, "About");
    //dialog.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    dialog.dispose();
```

Comment: The `showMessageDialog` method is `static` (you can't override it) and it creates its own `JOptionPane` object.

Comment: @Titus Thank you, do you know a solution for my problem?

Comment: For your debugging statements, don't use `System.out.println()`.  It won't necessarily print a line every time it is executed because `System.out` is a buffered stream.  Instead use `System.err.println()` for immediate guaranteed output.

Comment: @JoeCoder Thanks! I did not know that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `showMessageDialog` method is `static` (you can't override it) and it creates its own `JOptionPane` object.

You can reproduce what the `showMessageDialog` is doing, which is:

```
 /**
 * This method shows an INFORMATION_MESSAGE type message dialog.
 *
 * @param parentComponent The component to find a frame in.
 * @param message The message displayed.
 */
public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message){
  JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, null);
  dialog.show();   
}
```

And you can change it to something like this:

```
MyEffectPane pane = new MyEffectPane("message....", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(this, null);
dialog.show();
```

Also, you will have to add this constructor to your `MyEffectPane` class:

```
MyEffectPane(String message, int type){
    super(message, type);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! This works perfectly!! I just had do add some code in order for the components of the JDialog not to hide my drawins using `setOpaque(false)`.. I will update the post with the working code.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to draw an effect of one or more balls (circles) that move around in the background of the dialog and changeing their colors.

Don't use JOptionPane.

Instead you can create your of custom `JDialog`. Then you would add a JPanel to your dialog that does custom painting.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information.

Note, when doing custom painting your override `paintComponent(..)`, not paint(...).

Or if you want you can just add the custom JPanel to the JOptionPane. In any case the key is to do the custom painting on a JPanel.

Comment: Thank you too but the method from @Titus works perfectly. I tried this but the problem is that you have to make adjustments for your text, icon and the OK button in the JDialog in order to look good. Adding a panel works but you have only a small area where you can draw, it's the area where the text of a normal JDialog is located.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override JOptionPane. It is static and is mostly just used for ease of creating confirmation options.

For what you want, you can use JDialog. JDialog makes it easier for you to create a popup window with customized contents.

Since you're already trying to use a JOptionPane, I assume that you have a containing panel that triggers the JOptionPane. All you have to do is the following:

1. Use `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(panel)` to extract the containing window from your parent panel.
2. Use the extracted window to create the JDialog: `JDialog dialog = new JDialog(containerWindow)`
3. Customize the JDialog features to your liking.

Part of your code should look similar to this:

```
Window containerWindow = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(panel);
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(containerWindow);
dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(containerWindow);
dialog.setResizeable(false);
dialog.add(effectPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

In this case effectPanel is your own custom panel with the graphics and everything you want to do. This isn't the best way to write the code but i'm writing it down just as an example for you. You can view more of what JDialog is capable of here: [JDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html)

Comment: Thank you! This looks very interesting! I think it could be a problem that the resulting JDialog don't look so good because of using BorderLayout, so for example the OK button will get the full width size at the bottom. Or am I thinking wrong? However @Titus method works perfectly..

Comment: I only used BorderLayout as an example. You can use whatever layout you need. If you found an easier solution then that is great! 

If what you need to do to the option panel becomes a bit more complicated then JDialog might be more useful then.